# Re-project raster from dismo::gmap without losing colors

Tags: raster, r, google-maps, dismo

I downloaded a 'Google Map' terrain map using `dismo::gmap`. The raster comes with a Mercator projection. I tried to re-project it to UTM but in doing so, all the colors are lost and the raster is not displayed the same way (add scale + coordinates). Could you explain me how to retain the original colors ?

```
library(dismo)
library(raster)

area  <- extent(678815, 709272, 5004393, 5028388)
proj4 <- "+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"

r <- raster()
extent(r) <- area
proj4string(r) <- proj4

gm  <- gmap(x = r, type = "terrain", scale = 1)
gm2 <- projectRaster(gm, crs = proj4)


plot(gm)
plot(gm2)
```

[image: the two output]

Comment: Interesting Q! I suspect you may have to manually assign colours. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562387/re-color-google-terrain-map-in-r

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found the way with the option `rgb = TRUE` and the function `plotRGB`. It makes a lot of sense once you have the anwser.

```
library(dismo)
library(raster)

area  <- extent(678815, 709272, 5004393, 5028388)
proj4 <- "+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"

r <- raster()
extent(r) <- area
proj4string(r) <- proj4

gm  <- gmap(x = r, type = "terrain", scale = 1, rgb = TRUE)
gm2 <- projectRaster(gm, crs = proj4)


plotRGB(gm)
plotRGB(gm2)
```

Comment: (It's primarily because the default return is a palette image, that can be unpicked as well by applying the raster values as an index into the colour table. Here's an example I've had,  I use it for rgl texture mapping https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/7af4606fcbec6e110233b280974aba8f)   Didn't know about the rgb argument, thanks!

Comment: @mdsumner you should post as an answer with a bit more explanation :)